# Render precedence for multiple components in React

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, render

In my React app, I have a parent component that contains multiple children components:

```
$Components.ParentComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
     return (
       <div>
         <$Components.FirstChildrenComponent />
         <$Components.SecondChildrenComponent />
       </div>
     );
  }
});
```

In my `SecondChildrenComponent` I am using `componentDidMount(){ // start initializing some stuff }` to initialize some long running operation.

The problem is that it's only getting triggered after all the other components in my `ParentComponent` getting rendered.

I am trying to find the way how to improve performance/user experience by forcing React to render my `SecondChildrenComponent` before any other components of my `ParentComponent`, show it to the user while all the other elements are getting rendered.

My guess was that it has something to do with `ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, node);`

Maybe I can do something like:

```
$Components.ParentComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
     var secondComponent = ReactDOM.render(<$Components.SecondChildrenComponent />);

     return (
       <div>
        <$Components.FirstChildrenComponent />
        {secondComponent}
       </div>
     );
  }
});
```

But this is just a pseudo code, just wondering if there is any standard solution for this.

Comment: AFAIK, the `ReactDOM.render()` is to initialise a react tree. Nesting one inside another (by including a ReactDOM.render inside react code), as in your second pseudo-code, is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge React will render components in the order that they appear in your render function. Your options here, as far as I can tell, are:

1) Place `SecondChildrenComponent` first in your render function. Any layout issues caused can be fixed with CSS, especially if you're using flexbox (due to its excellent 'order' property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

2) Move your long-running function to the parent component and call it in that components `componentWillMount()` method. This won't work, of course, if your long-running function requires first that the second child component has finished mounting.

As an aside, React render functions may only return *one* root component. Your initial example contains two.

Comment: May have been an update to OP question, but both examples wrap the components inside a single `<div>`, so the render function returns only 1 root.

Comment: Yeah that looks like an update. Originally they weren't wrapped in a div.